# DB field called FileName causes error in mvc 4

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DB field called FileName, string. When I load the relative edit item view the reference to this field causes an error:

```
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FileName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileName)
    </div>
```

If I remove out the line: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FileName)`
all is well.
 The fieldname is correct and exists in the table. 
The error is:

`Format exception unhandled by user code
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.`

The field is String 100 chars, contains a string 30 chars and I am not trying to change the data type anywhere
. 
Any ideas please?

Comment: Instead of using @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FileName) use @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FileName) and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Tried that, same error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you put what your object looks like here ans well as your controller?

Comment: Thanks Brett Allred. I Rebuilt the thing from the ground up last night to see if I had made a mess, I also named the field that cuases the problem "DownloadName" instead of "FileName" as I thought maybe there might be some reserved word problem. Same error however, And if I comment out the "DownloadName" reference in the edit view it works fine. Anyway here is the model and controller:

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace AHGS.Models
{
    public class Downloads
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

Comment: [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Resource name")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "File Name")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {6} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string DownloadName { get; set; }

Comment: [Display(Name = "File size")]
        public string FileSize { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category ID")]
        public int PKCategory { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("PKCategory")]
        public virtual Categories Category { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Icon")]
        public string Icon { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Supplier name")]
        public string Supplier { get; set; }

Comment: [Display(Name = "Download count")]
        public int DownloadCount { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: [code]
 // GET: /Downloads/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.PKCategory = new SelectList(db.Category, "ID", "Category");
            return View();
        }

// POST: /Downloads/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Downloads downloads)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Download.Add(downloads);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

Comment: [code]

            ViewBag.PKCategory = new SelectList(db.Category, "ID", "Category", downloads.PKCategory);
            return View(downloads);
        }

Comment: you should edit your question and put this in there so it is formatted.  This is totally unreadable.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I neeed to work out how to post properly. Anyway I Have resolved the problem, it was in the model data annotation: **bold**ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {6} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)] should have been: ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)] I Should have checked the meaning of the params earlier. Thanks for your kind interest anyway.